# How to sum the value of same keys in an array with same type?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, ruby, sum

I have an array
`input`:

```
[
  { type: 1, price: 50, discounted_price: 40 }, 
  { type: 2, price: 150, discounted_price: 140 },
  { type: 1, price: 40, discounted_price: 30 },
  { type: 2, price: 140, discounted_price: 130 }
]
```

and what an expected output:

```
[
  { 
     type: 1, 
     price: 90, # =>  50 + 40
     discounted_price: 70 # =>  40 + 30
  },
  {
     type: 2,
     price: 290, # => 150 + 140
     discounted_price: 270 # => 140 + 130
  }
]
```

I already tried `reduce` and `group_by` methods but cannot understand.

https://medium.com/@james.a.hughes/using-the-reduce-method-in-ruby-907f3c18ae1f

```
input.group_by { |item| 
  [item[:type]] 
}.values.flat_map { |items| 
  items.first.merge(price: items.sum { |h| h[:price].to_f }) 
}
```

it sums the price but i want both the price and discounted price.

Comment: I suggest you remove the Rails tag as this is a pure-Ruby question. Consider also removing the "arrays" and "sum" tags as it's unlikely one would search on the former and the latter is somewhat misleading. That would leave just the "ruby" tag, which is perfectly fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `group_by` and `reduce`:

```
input.group_by { |item| item[:type] }.map do |_, collection|
  collection.reduce do |result, item| 
    result[:price] += item[:price]
    result[:discounted_price] += item[:discounted_price]
    result
  end
end
```

But using just `reduce` is enough as well:

```
input.reduce([]) do |result, item|
  result_i = result.find { |result_i| result_i[:type] == item[:type] }

  if result_i
    result_i[:price] += item[:price]
    result_i[:discounted_price] += item[:discounted_price]
    result
  else
    result << item 
  end
end
```

Comment: A small suggestion: if you use `each_with_object` rather than `reduce` you can get rid of that pesky line that contains `result` only. Also, you should point out that using `reduce` only comes at a cost: time-complexity goes from O(n) in #1 to O(n^2) in #2. As there are many O(n^2) ways of doing it I question whether using `reduce` only deserves mention.

Comment: You don't need `flat_map`; `map` is sufficient.

Answer (score 2):

```
arr = [
  { type: 1, price:  50, discounted_price:  40 }, 
  { type: 2, price: 150, discounted_price: 140 },
  { type: 1, price:  40, discounted_price:  30 },
  { type: 2, price: 140, discounted_price: 130 }
]
```

```
arr.each_with_object({}) do |g,h|
  h.update(g[:type]=>g) do |_,o,n|
    { type: o[:type], price: o[:price]+n[:price],
      discounted_price: o[:discounted_price] + n[:discounted_price] }
  end
end.values
  #=> [{:type=>1, :price=>90,  :discounted_price=>70},
  #    {:type=>2, :price=>290, :discounted_price=>270}]
```

Note that the receiver of `values` is

```
{1=>{:type=>1, :price=> 90, :discounted_price=> 70},
 2=>{:type=>2, :price=>290, :discounted_price=>270}}
```

This uses the form of [Hash#update](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Hash.html#method-i-update) (aka `merge!`) that employs the block

```
do |_,o,n|
  { type: o[:type], price: o[:price]+n[:price],
    discounted_price: o[:discounted_price] + n[:discounted_price] }
end
```

to determine the values of keys that are present in both hashes being merged. See the doc for definitions of the three block variables, `_`, `o` and `n`.

It's common practice to use an underscore for any block variable that is not used in the block calculation, mainly to so-inform the reader. Here the first block variable holds the common key. (Some might use `_k` for that block variable.)

`Hash#update` and [Enumerable#group_by](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-group_by) are closely-related in the sense that (as here) where one can be used the other could probably be used instead. The choice between the two is generally a stylistic preference.